# Read from file in playn

Tags: playn

Here's a stupid question.

How do you read files in a playn game? I tried using File and Scanner like I usually do in a standard java program:

```
    void readFromFile(){

    int x;
    int y;
    int pixel;
    int[][] board;

    try{

        Scanner scan = new Scanner(new File(in));

        x = scan.nextInt();
        y = scan.nextInt();
        pixel = scan.nextInt();
        Point start = new Point(scan.nextInt(), scan.nextInt());
        Point dir = new Point(scan.nextInt(), scan.nextInt());
        Point end = new Point(scan.nextInt(), scan.nextInt());
        int antRoads = scan.nextInt();

        board = new int[x][y];  

        for (int i = 0; i < y; i++){
            for (int j = 0; j < x; j++){
                board[i][j] = scan.nextInt();
            }
        }


        lev = new Level(board, start, dir, end, antRoads, pixel, x, y);


    } catch(FileNotFoundException e){
        System.out.println(e);
    }
}
```

I tested File.canRead(), canWrite() and can Execute() and they all returned false.

Am I supposed to use assetMannager().getText() or something? If that's the case can someone tell me how it works? (or what is and how ResourceCallback works?)

My goal is to have a folder named "Maps" filled with maps in regular text-format just like the standard Image folder.

Regards,
Torgeir

Answer (score 5):

You cannot do normal file I/O in a PlayN game, because the games are compiled into JavaScript and run in the browser (when using the HTML5 backend), and the browser supports no file I/O (at least not the general purpose file I/O you would need for these purposes).

Browsers also do not even support the idea of a byte stream, or any sort of binary I/O (this may eventually arrive, but it will be ages before it's supported for all browsers).

So you have to use `AssetManager.getText` to read data files. You can encode them in JSON if you like and use `PlayN.json()` to decode them, or you can use your own custom string-based format.

If you don't plan to deploy using the HTML5 backend, you can create a "LevelReader" interface and implement that interface in your Android or iOS backend and make use of the native file I/O capabilities on those platforms.